# Control Center infos are not updated with AVSpeechSynthesizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my app i'm using the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` object to use the TTS. I want to update the control center info box with some infos about the content i'm speaking with the synthesizer, but the infos are not displayed in the control center.
First of all i'm setting the `AVAudioSession` to work in background with

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.default)
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then i'm setting the `nowPlayingInfo` of the `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, setting some `MPMediaItemProperty` keys, but in the control center there is the music app and not my infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the method `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)`, without pass any option parameters, and you are able to show infos setted in `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` in the control center.